# How to leave only unique values in a List? - java

Tags: java

Basically, I have a model that stores two values `int keyScore` and `List<Integer> moves`. In the main class, I have a list of this model that is generated from calculation method.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Concatenate `List<Integer>` moves if the keyScore equals
2. Remove duplicates

I tried to use `HashSet` on `List<Integer>` move, when I find equal keyScore, but I ended up with duplicates of my model.

```
private class HeuristicResult {
        private int keyResult;
        private List<Integer> moves;

        private HeuristicResult(int keyResult, List<Integer> moves) {
            this.keyResult = keyResult;
            this.moves = moves;
        }

        private int getKeyResult(){
            return this.keyResult;
        }

        private List<Integer> getMoves(){
            return this.moves;
        }

        private void setMoves(List<Integer> moves){
            this.moves = moves;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s : %s", this.keyResult, this.moves);
        }
    }
private List<HeuristicResult> concatHeuristicResults(List<HeuristicResult> heuristicResultsList){
            List<HeuristicResult> heuristicResults = heuristicResultsList;
            for(int i =0; i<heuristicResults.size()-2; i++){
                int score = heuristicResults.get(i).getKeyResult();
                for(int j = 0; j<heuristicResults.size()-1;j++){
                    if(score == heuristicResults.get(j).getKeyResult()){
                        heuristicResults.get(i).getMoves().addAll(heuristicResults.get(j).getMoves());
                        Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<>(heuristicResults.get(i).getMoves());
                        heuristicResults.get(i).setMoves(new ArrayList<>(temp));
                    }
                }
            }
            return heuristicResults;
        }
```

This is what I get as an output when I try to concatenate:

```
1 : [0, 1]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
-10 : [3]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
-1 : [0, 1, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
0 : [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
-1 : [0, 1, 7, 8]
0 : [6]
0 : [6]
```

Comment: Could it be that you are getting a match (==) when comparing against itself? when i == j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static Collection<HeuristicResult> concatenate(List<HeuristicResult> list) {
    HashMap<Integer, HeuristicResult> keys = new HashMap<>();

    for (HeuristicResult x: list) {
        HeuristicResult hr = keys.get(x.keyResult);

        if (hr != null) {
            // Merge hr and x.
            Set<Integer> moves = new HashSet<>();
            moves.addAll(hr.getMoves());
            moves.addAll(x.getMoves());

            hr.moves.clear();
            hr.moves.addAll(moves);
        }
        else {
            // Create a new entry into our keys map if it doesn't exist.
            keys.put(x.keyResult, x);
        }
    }
    return keys.values();
}
```

You're trying to merge hierarchically. First, you want unique `keyResult`s and for each of these unique `keyResult`s you want to merge `moves`. That's 2 levels of merging.

The `HashMap` (`keyResult` -> `HeuristicResult`) keeps only unique `keyResult`s and maps them against the first `HeuristicResult` it sees in the list. Then during the iteration if it finds the same `keyResult` again, it pulls out the `moves` from the map and the one found in iteration and merges them. The merged `Set` is put back into the list (by clearing it first).

Comment: That solved my problem! Maybe you could explain what I did wrong? And I see you are HashMap instead, why? Thank you!